# The packet not reaching destination when broadcasted with address 255.255.255.255

Tags: networking, ip-address

I have a bacnet application which broadcast a message to all devices connected. When i use the address 10.9.x.255, it works and the device is able to get the response but when i use the global broadcast 255.255.255.255, the packet is not reaching the device it has to reach.

What may be the reason for this? I can use the address 10.9.x.255 but i would like to know the reason behind it.

On a different computer it works with global broadcast address but does not work on a specific computer. both computers running on windows 10.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you seen this? https://serverfault.com/questions/219764/255-255-255-255-vs-192-168-1-255